# perturbation of sub-Gaussian vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a sub-Gaussian random vector with parameter $R$ such that $\lVert x\rVert \leq C$. Given a perturbation matrix $P$ such that $\lVert P \rVert \leq \delta$. It is my intuition that $(I + P)x$ is also sub-Gaussian with some new parameter if we can enssure $\delta$ is small enough. However, that does not seem to be true, as for any $u$

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(e^{u^\top (I + P) x}\right) &\leq e^{\lVert u \rVert\delta C} \mathbb{E}\left(e^{u^{\top}x}\right)
\\
&\leq \exp\left(\frac{\lVert u \rVert^2 R^2}{2} + \lVert u \rVert \delta C\right)
\end{align*}

which can not be put into the sub-Guassian form. Does that mean perturbation of sub-Gaussian vector is not guaranteed to be sub-Gaussian no matter how small the perturbation is? Or do we need some more assumption about $P$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random vector $x$ is said to be subGaussian if for each unit vector $u$, $\langle u, x\rangle $ is subGaussian. But then note that for any matrix $A$, $\langle u , A x\rangle = \langle A^\top u, x\rangle = \|A^\top u\| \langle v,x\rangle,$ where $v $ is a unit vector. We know that $\langle v,x\rangle $ is subGaussian, and so $\langle u ,Ax\rangle$ is just a scaling of a subGaussian random variable, and so is subGaussian if the scaling factor is finite. Therefore, as long as $ M := \sup_{\|u\|= 1} \|A^\top u\| < \infty,$ we can conclude that $Ax$ is subGaussian. It should also be simple to work out the loss in the subGaussianity parameter you would suffer (work this out).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your quantity $M$ is simply the operator norm of $A^T$.